# using jquery with typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript

I am new to this so bear with me. What i am trying to do is getting jquery to work in a typescript code file.

How should i refer to the .d.ts code?

I have tried the following:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

this gives me the error: "'jquery' resolves to non-module entity and cannot be imported with this construct"

then i tried:

```
import $ = require("jquery");
```

this gives the following error:
Import assignment cannot be used when targeting EcmaScript 2015 modules

How do I go about this to make jquery functions work in my typescript code? Are there other ways?

I am using typescript 2.5.2, module system ES2015, EcmaScript 6 and @types/jquery.

---

EDIT

i tried `import * as $ from "../wwwroot/lib/jQuery/dist/jquery.min.js"`;, now it gives me the error "... has been resolved ... but --allowJs is not set",I dont have a tsconfig.json yet, I probably need it for the --allowJs command, is that right?

Comment: Try to use relative path to jquery: `import * as $ from "path/to/jquery";`

Comment: I am doing `import * as jQuery from 'jquery'`. It should work if jQuery is installed through NPM.

Comment: (at least with TypeScript 2.3.4 it works)

Comment: i have installed it through npm as well, i am gonna try to be more specific with my path

Comment: i tried  ``import * as $ from "../node_modules/@types/jquery";`` and import * as $ from ``"../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts";`` and it doesnt work either

Comment: Here is my jquery in `node_module`, you need to import highlighted file, not from `@types`: https://ibb.co/nPvjpQ

Comment: You don't have to import the .d.ts file. It should be automatically detected by your IDE. The .d.ts file is not a module, it only enables type completion. That being said, you CAN use jQuery as a module if you really want, but only if you already use modules in your build system.

Comment: And what are the other options to get jquery working in my code? I just started my project and I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

add a reference to the Typescript definition file the top of the file.

```
/// <reference path ="jquery.d.ts"/>
```

instead of

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

According to the DefinitelyTyped wiki:

> A TypeScript declaration file is way of defining the types, functions
>   and parameters in an external third-party JavaScript library. By using
>   a declaration file in your TypeScript code will enable Intellisense
>   and type checking against the external library you are using.

jquery.d.ts is a part of the DefinitelyTyped Library found on [GitHub](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/jquery).
and also you can install via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery).

Comment: this compiles, but the resulting .js file does not contain a definition of jquery and thus fails to execute

Comment: You have to add jquery.js file to page for executing jquery functions.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know it this is a "correct way" of doing things, but i use the following line in my typescript project to use jquery.

```
const jquery = require('jquery');
// and then later in your class
jquery('.someclass').show();
```

Comment: it gives me the error "Cannot find name 'require' "

Comment: If you want to use `require`, you need to declare it: `declare function require(moduleName: string): any;`